# How do I properly execute and rollback multiple steps in a transaction including DB write, blob upload and async messaging?

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core, transactions, transactionscope

I must execute the following three steps in a single transaction.

1. Store an entity in Postgres via EF Core
2. Upload a document to an Azure blob container
3. Send a notification via an Azure Service Bus queue

I am looking for a way to implement this as a compensatable transaction. So if e.g., uploading of the blob in step 2) fails, the entity is removed from the database (rollback).

So basically, I would wrap these operations with a transaction scope like so...

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Step 1
    await _repository.AddAsync(entity);
    
    // Step 2
    var response = await _blobContainerClient.UploadBlobAsync(...);
    
    // Step 3
    await _serviceBusClient.CreateSender("service-bus-queue").SendMessageAsync(...)

    scope.Commit();
}
```

According to the documentation, EF Core supports ambient transactions. And if I get that right, there is nothing more for me to do. If any operations/steps fail/throw an exception, the database operation (INSERT) will be rolled back (as long as the database provider supports it, which should be the case for npgsql).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#using-systemtransactions

But what about the other steps? Do I have to write my own resource managers wrapping the blob container client and another one wrapping the service bus client?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-a-resource-manager

In case of a rollback, a compensating operation for the blob upload would be something like a `TryDelete(...)`.

But how about the message-sending part? Am I going in the right direction with `System.Transactions`?

Since the transaction is not spanning multiple microservices components, I think the saga pattern wouldn't be the right candidate here, right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you end up solving this?